# How to manage image assets gracefully in react-native?

Tags: react-native, assets

I have a lot of picture to manage in plenty of screens.Every time I load the image like

```
<Image source={require("../../images/001.png")} style={styles.image1}/>
```

But it is too tedious as it has too many to write and hard to manage.

I want to manage the images together.Like

```
  export default function loadImages(){
     return {
        img1:require("../../images/001.png"),
        img2:require("../../images/002.png"),
        ...
     }
  }
```

Then use it like so.

```
import Images from "image.js"
<Image source={Images.img1} />
```

But I am worried that the object returned will be too large and cost too much memory resource.Will it be?Do anyone has some graceful solution?

Comment: have you test the memory difference between using `Image.img1` and `require(image_path)` ? btw how about `export const Image1 = require(path)` and then import it by `import {Image1} from 'image.js`?

Comment: I don't know how to test that.I am new to react-native.